# How to get the id of some images with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html I have some images with same class name but different ids.

```
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:25px; HEIGHT:20px; background:red;" SRC="../image_collection/xx.png" class="allBtns" id="btn1">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:50px; WIDTH:25px; HEIGHT:20px; background:red;" SRC="../image_collection/yy.png" class="allBtns" id="btn2">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:295px; LEFT:250px; WIDTH:25px; HEIGHT:20px; background:red;" SRC="../image_collection/yy.png" class="allBtns" id="btn3">
..........
```

If i click an image I want the ID of the image that has been clicked.

I have tried the following by it returns full list of ids:

```
$(".allBtns").on("click", function(event)
    {
        var ids = $('.allBtns').map(function() {
        return this.id;
        }).get();

        alert(ids);
    })
```

How do I get the image ID that's been clicked?

Comment: If you want the one that is clicked, why are you looping over lal of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the current element clicked.

```
$(".allBtns").on("click", function(event) {
     alert(this.id); // alert the id of current element
 });
```

Comment: event.currentTarget refers to element clicked, this may refer to some other element, depending on the event propagation

Comment: @Tushar Gupta : thanks a lot. also, can you please tell me another solution. In my question I am getting the ids as list, so shouldn't I be able to get the first ids using ids[0]

Comment: @RashedulHasan you are mapping all the ids, so if you do `ids[0]` you will always get the first element present in the DOM, which may not the element clicked. So let's say you have 3 elements with id `elOne`, `elTwo`, `elThree` with `ids[0]` you will always get `elOne` .

Comment: @Tushar Gupta : then how do i get the first ids for this class or from this ids list?

Comment: @RashedulHasan `this` will refer to the current div clicked with class `.allBtns`, so when we try to do `this.id` it will give the currently clicked div `id`.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide Can you please check http://jsfiddle.net/etv9joz3/1/ and reproduce the scenario where `this.id` will fail?

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to get the `id` using event target:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".allBtns").on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:25px; HEIGHT:20px; background:red;" SRC="../image_collection/xx.png" class="allBtns" id="btn1">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:50px; WIDTH:25px; HEIGHT:20px; background:red;" SRC="../image_collection/yy.png" class="allBtns" id="btn2">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:295px; LEFT:250px; WIDTH:25px; HEIGHT:20px; background:red;" SRC="../image_collection/yy.png" class="allBtns" id="btn3">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('.hello').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      
     $('.input').val(id);
      
 });
```

```css
<button class='hello'>click to get Id</button>
<button class='hello'>click to get Id</button>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='hello' id='1'>click to get Id</button>
<button class='hello' id='2'>click to get Id</button>

<input class='input' type="text" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.allBtns').on('click', function(e){
     console.log(this.id);
     console.log(e.target.id)
})
```